# How can I write <input> tags inside a for loop in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, angular

How can I add `<input>` tags inside a for loop?

We had a number of 6, so I want 6 `input` tags to be rendered in the UI.
What would be the code for that?

```js
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
          <label for="tsize">Team Size:</label>
            <select id="dropdown" onChange={this.handleDropdownChange}>
              <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div>Selected value is : {this.state.selectValue}</div>
          {
            for (let i = 0; i< this.state.selectValue; i++) {
              <input type="text" />
              
            }
          }
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
    <div>
      <div>Selected value is : {this.state.selectValue}</div>
      {[...Array(this.state.selectValue)].map((_, i) => {
        return <input key={i} type="text" />
      })}
    </div>
```

You may use for loop here as well instead of [...Array(n)].map().

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class InputList extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  inputValues: ['', '', '', '', '', ''], // Initialize with 6 empty strings
};
}handleInputChange = (index, event) => {
const { inputValues } = this.state;
inputValues[index] = event.target.value;
this.setState({ inputValues });
 };render() {
const { inputValues } = this.state;

return (
  <div>
    {inputValues.map((value, index) => (
      <input
        key={index}
        type="text"
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => this.handleInputChange(index, e)}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
);
  }};
export default InputList;
```